# htaccess redirect adds additional ?videos=blabla

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect this structure of pages

example.com/y/T5INF08ZEdA/Miranda-Kerr-In-Hot-Water-with-Orlando-Bloom

to

example.com/s/Miranda-Kerr-In-Hot-Water-with-Orlando-Bloom

My htaccess is

```
RewriteRule ^s/(.*)$ index.php?videos=$1

RedirectMatch 301 ^/?y/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/s/$2 [R=301,L]
```

However, it redirects to

example.com/s/T5INF08ZEdA?videos=T5INF08ZEdA/Miranda-Kerr-In-Hot-Water-with-Orlando-Bloom

What is the correct way to do this redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's weird that your `RedirectMatch` works at all, since there isn't a 2nd capture group (`$2` should be blank).

Try sticking with just mod_rewrite, it's possible that the two directives are interferring with each other:

```
RewriteRule ^y/([^/]+)/(.*)$ /s/$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^s/(.*)$ index.php?videos=$1 [L]
```

Comment: @user198989 If you removed the `RedirectMatch`, then there's something else that is causing the redirect, it's not these 2 rules.